# Sharepoint 2007 How can I fix "operation for file.doc was rejected by custom validation on the server"?

Tags: sharepoint

Using Sharepoint 2007 when I open a file and click Save (in Word) I see the error:

```
 Operation for file.doc was rejected by custom validation on the server.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a custom event handler setup that is doing some validation on the document during upload. If you get this codeplex utility:
http://www.codeplex.com/spstipsUtilityPack

You can point it to your site/list and it will tell you about any event handlers that are setup on the list. From there you can determine if you need to delete the handler or fix the problem that is making the document get rejected.

Answer (score 0):

I would gather some more information.

- Use Fiddler to capture the traffic from the client to the server.  See if there is anything obvious in the communication.
- Take a look at the Event Logs on the server to see if there is anything obvious.